# ado.net:The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, web-config

there are a lot of topic on this issue however all of them suggest the main project is in a separate place with web.config which in my case it is not...I'm using ado.net in framework 4 and the connection string that I'm using is:

```
<add name="db_parspooshEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/db_ParsPoosh.csdl|res://*/db_ParsPoosh.ssdl|res://*/db_ParsPoosh.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=db_parspoosh;user id=myid;password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

this is the first time I'm encountering this issue...is there sth wrong with the connection string?
or it is the database problem?...

............................................

Edit:this is the picture of the structure I'm using:

[image: this is the picture of the structure I'm using:]

Comment: if you can show the structure of your project, that might help us to answer your question. As to predict the issue just from the connection string is not possible.

Comment: tnx for the answer...I edited my question and added the structure

Comment: make sure the connection name you are using is "db_parspooshEntities" to connect within the application, as the structure is simple and don't seem anything wrong.

Comment: tnx...I finally got the problem..the problem was my new database as I switched to my older database for another project the problem got solved however I have no idea what was the problem at the first place but I suppose if I make my database table all over again it would be no problem any more...

Comment: Glad to know, your issue got resolved. :)